# java Arrays.binarySearch() not able to find string in case insensitive search

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-7, binary-search

I am trying to use the binary search (case insensitive) of java.util.Arrays class but it is not able to search a String which exists in the array specified.
Below is the program :

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestArrayBinSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String arr[] = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String searchString = "UTC";

        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, searchString, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        if(index >= 0)
           System.out.println("Found: " + arr[index]);
        else 
            System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
}
```

Below is the output based on different values of search strings:

- searchString = "UTC"  ---> output = Not Found
- searchString = "america/los_angeles"  ---> output = Found: America/Los_Angeles

If I remove the String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER parameter from the binarySearch parameters then UTC is also found. 
What am I missing here ? I need to do a case insensitive search over this array.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Probably the order of the values in `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs` are in case sensitive order, not in case insensitive order, so it cannot find it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Arrays.binarySearch()* states in JavaDoc that the result is undefined if the array is not in ascending order. The problem is that you are sorting your array with a different *Comparator* than the one you pass to *binarySearch* method. So your result is undefined ... in this case not found.

Pass the Comparator to array sorting

```
Arrays.sort(arr, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: I think resorting an array you got from a core API is a bad idea. Not just because you have to resort it every time you want to use in case it is a copy of the data, but also because in case not a copy, other consumers of the same API will get unexpected results (though its JavaDoc does not state anything about the ordering) (like they cannot find UTC with case sensitive binarySearch).

Comment: You are right. And as I read my 2cents again, it does not really answer the question, because there is no case insensitive searching done at all.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine the order of the time zone ids are the following for `U`:

```
java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs.filter(_.startsWith("U"))
```

> res0: Array[String] = Array(UCT, US/Alaska, US/Aleutian, US/Arizona, US/Central, US/East-Indiana, US/Eastern, US/Hawaii, US/Indiana-Starke, US/Michigan, US/Mountain, US/Pacific, US/Pacific-New, US/Samoa, UTC, Universal)

As you can see, `Universal` is after `UTC`, so in case insensitive order, this is not ordered, you cannot use `binarySearch` in this case.

I would suggest cache a `SortedSet` (`TreeSet`) with case insensitive order of these ids and use that for searching.